# Chrome Extension SQLite fails since version 60: Iterator getter is not callable

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-chrome

> When **transaction.executeSQL (sql, args, function(_, result)** gets called

I get:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'executeSql' on
>   'SQLTransaction': Iterator getter is not callable.**

the code is:

```
function executeSql(sql, args, resultCallback, transactionCallback) {
  DB.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql(sql, args, function(_, result) {
      (resultCallback || $.noop)(result);
    });
  }, $.noop, (transactionCallback || $.noop));
}
```

I guess this is linked to the Chrome version 60 security fix:

> [742407] Medium CVE-2017-7000: Pointer disclosure in SQLite

Do you know how can I change my code in a way to avoid the error?
In the previous versions of Google Chrome it was working properly.

Comment: Hi @Alberto, I am also facing the same issue. If you got any solution Please post here as an answer. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Hi Alberto, in what format are you passing your arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
transaction.executeSql(sql, [], function(_, result) {
  (resultCallback || $.noop)(result);
});
```

**Use this this worked for me.**